# UIView drawRect drawing black when embedded

Tags: swift

I have custom drawing happening in the drawRect method of a subclassed UIView. It is working nicely, as long as it is the initial view controller. As soon as I embed it within a navigation controller it draws completely black.

I should also note, I've flagged the subclassed UIView as IBDesignable and it is actually still drawing properly within interface builder. It only has this problem when building.

Another test I've done is connecting to a UITabBarController rather than UINavigationController. The view draws properly with the UITabBarController.

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: I hope your view controller is the root view controller and you are adding the sub classed UIView to the view controller's view. Am i right?

Comment: Yep, thats what it was. I should have known better. Just missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the view to the navigation controller incorrectly. It was connected to show segue rather than root relationship controller.